# Need help using Enumerable

Tags: ruby, rubygems

Trying to read file containing a list of information, it's a .dtf file. The information is in 1 paragraph per point. Example:

```
ID : 001
category : 2
length : 18.33

ID : 002
category : 1
length : 19.75

ID : 003
category : 1
length : 18.8

ID : 004
category : 3
length : 17.9

ID : 005
category : 3
length : 16.9

ID : 006
category : 2
length : 17.9

ID : 007
category : 3
length : 21.5

ID : 008
category : 1
length : 20.7

ID : 009
category : 1
length : 16.5

ID : 010
category : 1
length : 23

ID : 011
category : 2
length : 18.73

ID : 012
category : 3
length : 17.9

ID : 013
category : 3
length : 23.4

ID : 014
category : 3
length : 17.9

ID : 015
category : 3
length : 20.93
```

and so on..

Need to group the category and total the length for each group.
Anybody can help?

Succeeded in grouping the category but did not manage to get total of the length.

```
a = IO.readlines("point.txt")
b = Hash.new(0)
a.each do |v|
  b[v] +=1
end
b.each do |k, v|
  puts "#{k} occurs #{v}"
end
b = Hash.new(0)
```

The expected output:

```
Category 1 : 5 points
Total length : 98.75

Category 2 : 3 points
Total length : 54.96

Category 3 : 7 points
Total length : 136.43
```

Comment: It is unclear what are you trying to achieve. Please post the desired output.

Comment: The expected output: Category 1 : 5 points Total length : 98.75

Category 2 : 3 points Total length : 54.99

Category 3 : 7 points Total length : 118.53

Comment: Can you add full input data related to the same category (e.g. 1) useful to determinate the output `Category 1 : 5 points Total length : 98.75`?

Comment: _"Succeeded in grouping the category"_ – you are merely traversing the lines. I don't see any grouping. Try to split the data into chunks, so you can convert each data chunk to a Ruby object, e.g. `{id: '001', category: 2, length: 6.3}`. Then group those objects by category and finally sum their lengths.

Comment: if read the list from a file, how do u split the data into chunks?

Comment: Roche, I happened to stumble onto this question, to which I previously offered a solution. I noticed that my answer could be improved by taking a different approach, so I did an edit.

Answer (score 2):

I've copied the string in your example to the file `'temp'`. We can efficiently obtain a hash that can be used to display the desired result as follows.

```
category = nil
h = IO.foreach('temp').
       each_with_object(Hash.new {|h,k| h[k]={points: 0, length: 0}}) do |line,h|
         case line[/\p{L}+/]
         when 'category'
           category = line[/\d+/]
           h[category][:points] += 1
         when 'length'
           h[category][:length] += line[/[\d.]+/].to_f
         end
       end
  #=> {"2"=>{:points=>3, :length=>54.959999999999994},
  #    "1"=>{:points=>5, :length=>98.75},
  #    "3"=>{:points=>7, :length=>136.43}}
```

We can then use this hash to display the desired results.

```
h.sort_by(&:first).each do |k,v|
  puts "Category #{k} : #{v[:points]} points"      
  puts "Total length : #{v[:length].round(2)}"
  puts      
end
```

displays:

```
Category 1 : 5 points
Total length : 98.75

Category 2 : 3 points
Total length : 54.96

Category 3 : 7 points
Total length : 136.43
```

[IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) is a very useful method. Not only does it read files line-by-line (which may be essential for large files) and close the file when finished, but it returns an enumerator when no block is given, permitting it to be chained to other methods.<sup>1</sup> Here I've chained it to [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) with the associated object being:

```
Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = { points: 0, length: 0 } }
```

The doc [Hash::new](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-c-new) explains that this constructs an empty hash with an attached default proc; that is, it is the same as:

```
h = {}
pr = proc { |h,k| h[k] = { points: 0, length: 0 } }
  #=> #<Proc:0x000059d3963150b0@(irb):84> 
h.default_proc = pr
  #=> #<Proc:0x000059d3963150b0@(irb):84>
```

See [Hash#default_proc=](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc-3D).

This simply means that if `h[k]` is executed when `h` does not have a key `k`, `h[k]` is set equal to the value of the proc when it is called with arguments `h` and `k`. For example (since `h` is empty and therefore has no keys),

```
h['cat']
  #=> {:points=>0, :length=>0} 
h #=> {"cat"=>{:points=>0, :length=>0}}
```

Now let's try:

```
h['dog'][:points] += 1
  #=> 1 
h #=> {"cat"=>{:points=>0, :length=>0}, "dog"=>{:points=>1, :length=>0}}
```

Ruby executes the first of these expressions in two steps:

```
g = h['dog']
  #=> {:points=>0, :length=>0}
g[:points] += 1
```

The next time `h['dog'][:points] += 1` is executed the default proc is not called because `h` now has a key `'dog'`.

Lastly, `category` must be initialised (to any object) outside the loop it order for its value to survive from one line to the next.<sup>2</sup>

<sup>1. `foreach` is often executed on `File`, rather than `IO`. That is permissible because `File` is a subclass of `IO`.</sup>

<sup>2. If that is not done, Ruby will first set the variable `category` to its value in the first line of the file. It will then go out of scope after the block calculation is performed, but at that point Ruby does not "undefine" the variable; instead, for reasons of performance, it sets it to `nil`. It therefore would equal `nil` when the second line of the file is read, and so on.</sup>

Comment: Thank u for your feedback @Cary Swoveland. May I know what these : **[/\p{L}+/]** and **[/\d+/]** mean?

Comment: `line[<regular expression>]` means the portion of the string held by `line` that matches the given regular expression ("regex") is to be returned (or `nil` is returned if there is no match). See the doc [String#\[\]](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/String.html#method-i-5B-5D).  `/\p{L}+/` reads, "match a sequence of one or more (`+`) Unicode letters (`p{L}`)". `/\d+/` reads, "match a sequence of one or more digits". `/[\d.]+/` reads, "match a sequence of one or more digits or periods". Search for `\p{L}` in [Regexp](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Regexp.html).

Answer (score 2):

If each "point entry" starts with `ID`, you can use [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) to split the data accordingly, e.g.:

```
IO.foreach('point.txt').slice_before(/^ID/).each do |lines|
   # ...
end
```

The result can then be mapped to a more manageable object, for example a hash:

```
points = IO.foreach('point.txt').slice_before(/^ID/).map do |lines|
  lines.each_with_object({}) do |line, h|
    case line
    when /^ID : (.*)/
      h[:id] = $1
    when /^category : (.*)/
      h[:category] = $1.to_i
    when /^length : (.*)/
      h[:length] = $1.to_f
    end
  end
end
#=> [
#     {:id=>"001", :category=>2, :length=>18.33},
#     {:id=>"002", :category=>1, :length=>19.75},
#     # ...
#   ]
```

We can now group the points by category:

```
grouped_points = points.group_by { |h| h[:category] }
```

and print the results:

```
grouped_points.each do |category, points|
  puts "Category #{category} : #{points.length} points"
  puts "Total length : #{ points.sum { |p| p[:length] }.round(2) }"
  puts
end
```

Output:

```
Category 2 : 3 points
Total length : 54.96

Category 1 : 5 points
Total length : 98.75

Category 3 : 7 points
Total length : 136.43
```

You might want to sort the `grouped_points`.

Comment: If the file is large you may want `points` to be something like `[[2, 18.33], [1, 19.75],...]`. Note that there's no need to carry the values of `:id` forward.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you're actually just counting the unique lines without the actual processing. You need to parse the file line by line, extract key-value pairs from each line and associate the points with categories somehow - only after that your calculations make sense.

In the simplest case, if the data structure is robust enough and the length always follows the category, the parsing might be as trivial as

```rb
text = StringIO.new(<<~DATA)
  ID : 001
  category : 2
  length : 6.30

  ID : 002
  category : 1
  length : 17.9

  ID : 003
  category : 2
  length : 3.70

DATA

categories = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = {count: 0, length: 0} }
current_cat = nil

text.each_line do |line|
  next if line.strip.empty?
  key, value = line.split(":").map(&:strip)

  case key
  when "category"
    current_cat = value
    categories[current_cat][:count] += 1
  when "length"
    categories[current_cat][:length] += Float(value)
  end
end

puts categories.inspect # => {"2"=>{:count=>2, :length=>10.0}, "1"=>{:count=>1, :length=>17.9}}
```

(just replace stringio with reading from a file to map it to your use case)

Answer (score 0):

More or less the same soup as showed in other answers.

Once you read the file, `a` contains:

```
#=> ["ID : 001\n", "category : 2\n", "length : 18.33\n", "\n", "ID : 002\n", "category : 1\n", "length : 19.75\n", "\n", "ID : 003\n", "category : 1\n", "length : 18.8\n", "\n", "ID : 004\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 17.9\n", "\n", "ID : 005\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 16.9\n", "\n", "ID : 006\n", "category : 2\n", "length : 17.9\n", "\n", "ID : 007\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 21.5\n", "\n", "ID : 008\n", "category : 1\n", "length : 20.7\n", "\n", "ID : 009\n", "category : 1\n", "length : 16.5\n", "\n", "ID : 010\n", "category : 1\n", "length : 23\n", "\n", "ID : 011\n", "category : 2\n", "length : 18.73\n", "\n", "ID : 012\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 17.9\n", "\n", "ID : 013\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 23.4\n", "\n", "ID : 014\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 17.9\n", "\n", "ID : 015\n", "category : 3\n", "length : 20.93"]
```

Then you need to convert this mess into a more comfortable object, an Array of Hashes is the best option, so:

```
res = a.map{ |e| e.chomp.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(':') }.reject(&:empty?).each_slice(3).map(&:to_h)
#=> [{"ID"=>"001", "category"=>"2", "length"=>"18.33"}, {"ID"=>"002", "category"=>"1", "length"=>"19.75"}, {"ID"=>"003", "category"=>"1", "length"=>"18.8"}, ...
```

Maybe it's better to have `length` value as a float:

```
res.map { |h| h['length'] = h['length'].to_f }
```

Finally, grouping by `"category"` and transforming the values of the resulting hash:

```
res.group_by { |h| h['category']}.transform_values { |v| [v.size, v.sum { |h| h['length'] }] }
#=> {"2"=>[3, 54.959999999999994], "1"=>[5, 98.75], "3"=>[7, 136.43]}
```

---

One liner, just for fun:

```
a.map{ |e| e.chomp.gsub(/\s+/, "").split(':') }.reject(&:empty?).each_slice(3).map(&:to_h).tap { |res| res.map { |h| h['length'] = h['length'].to_f } }.group_by { |h| h['category']}.transform_values { |v| [v.size, v.sum { |h| h['length'] }] }
```

Comment: i got "undefined method 'transform_values'" what should i do?

Comment: Which version of Ruby are you running?

Comment: 1.9.3 is the ruby version matter?

Comment: Absolutely. You are missing great features. Consider to upgrade. Last version is 2.6.3: https://ruby-doc.org/